# How to check CPU temperature on BAMT (Debian)

Tags: linux, debian, temperature, bitcoin, sensors

How can I check CPU temperature on BAMT? BAMT is Debian based bitcoin/litecoin mining distribution (kernel is 2.6.32-41 32 bit version).

I've tried with **lm-sensors**, every time I'm using, I'm recieving the same values:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +27.8Â°C  (crit = +106.0Â°C)
temp2:       +29.8Â°C  (crit = +106.0Â°C)
```

I've been using **sensors-detect**, I've even added 'lm78' module to */etc/modules*, as it was suggested to me, but result is the same all the time.

I've also tried with *cat /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/TZ01/temperature*, but is also shows the same temps all the time.

How can I check CPU temperatures on BAMT than? I suffering from random freezes of mining rig, and I'm guessing that I've got problems with CPU / motherboard overheating.

Rig specs:

- **MOBO**: MSI Z77A-GD55
- **CPU**: Intel Celeron G1610
- **RAM**: Good Ram DDR3 4 GB /1333MHz
- **GPU**: 6x Asus 280X
- **PSU** 2x1000W OCZ-FTY1000W-EU

Answer (score 0):

```
/opt/bamt/getgpustat all current_temp_0
```

Comment: this gives me GPU temperatures, but I want to get CPU ones